# Pandas - Create dataframe with only one row from dictionary containing lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
d = {'val_1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'val_2': 4}
```

And I want to create a pandas DataFrame from this with only one row.

When I do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

I get 5 rows:

```
    val_1   val_2
0   1       4
1   2       4
2   3       4
3   4       4
4   5       4
```

However, when I append it to the existing dataframe, I get the behavior I want.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.append(d, ignore_index=True)
print(df)

    val_1           val_2
0   1               4
1   2               4
2   3               4
3   4               4
4   5               4
5   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 4
```

How can I create the dataframe from the dict, and get only one row as in the append case?

```
    val_1             val_2
0   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   4
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap the values in a list:

```
pd.DataFrame({k: [v] for k, v in d.items()})
#             val_1   val_2
#0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]       4
```

Answer (score 11):

You can start with `pd.Series` instead:

```
pd.Series(d).to_frame().T

             val_1 val_2
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]     4
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `from_dict` but the order of columns is interchanged:

```
In[151]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index').T
Out[151]: 
  val_2            val_1
0     4  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can using

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=d.keys())
df.append(d, ignore_index=True)
Out[26]: 
             val_1 val_2
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]     4
```

Comment: This returns `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` when I run it... any idea?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Let me check , It works fine on my side ... wired

Comment: I'm running python3.6 with IPython 6.2.1, if it helps. `d` is the same from the question

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ something  funny just happen , I can not reproduce the issue , trust me when I run it , it work , right now it dose not work any more ..

Comment: Weird, I think your `d` may have been different before. Anyway, it's working nicely now.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ update another way , I will check it out , once I find the problem , will let you know man